# How to create an Observable that depends on another Observable in RxJS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a cart service that provides reactive data about the cart:

```
export interface OrderItem {
  product: IProduct
  quantity: number
}

private subject = new BehaviorSubject<OrderItem[]>([])
private orderItems: Observable<OrderItem[]> = this.subject.asObservable()

getItems(): Observable<OrderItem[]> {
    return this.orderItems
  }
```

I want to create a method that will return an **Observable** of the number of products in the cart, like this (pseudo-code):

```
return getItems().subscribe(items => {
  let cartSize = 0
  items.forEach(item => cartSize += item.quantity)
})
```

So basically to return `cartSize` as an observable, how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an observable depending on another observable (which would call for operators like for example mergeMap, switchMap and withLatestFrom), but it is merely a transformation of your observable. This would be a map.

For example:

```
const totalQuantity$ = getItems().pipe(
  map(items => {
    // this would be nicer using a reduce but ok
    let cartSize = 0
    items.forEach(item => cartSize += item.quantity)
    return cartSize
   })
 )
```

And then subscribe to totalQuantity$ somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Not related, but you can remove this `orderItems` property, and refactor the `getItems` method to:

```js
getItems(): Observable<OrderItem[]> {
  return this.subject.asObservable()
}
```

Anyways, if you use some pipe operators in this method, than you simply can work on `this.subject`, because all of pipes returns `Observable`

Comment: But then each time I call `getItems()` i will get a new reference of observable, am I right? that's why I used a property

Comment: Yes, but... if you want to use hot observable then you can use share() operator or... use BehaviorSubject :) So - IMO - that conversion is not necessary at all.